# Is Python's mmap the same as C#'s memorymappedfile

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, memory-mapped-files

I am wondering if [C#'s memory-mapped file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd997372(v=vs.100)) (I know it is not C# only - just to be clear) the same as [Python's mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)?

I mean I am getting the expression both is just a wrapper for the OS-API (Win10 Server in this case).

Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: You can see for yourself how Python's `mmap` is implement by reading its source code. I don't believe the same is can be said of C#, so all anyone could say is "probably".

Comment: Sure we can: [MemoryMappedFile] (https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.cs) but I was really hoping not having to do this